# mongoose schema ref to nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ref

I'm using mongoose in a project that is going to store businesses in different categories in the database. The businesses are going to refer to a category using mongoose `ref`. And this is the category schema:

```js
const categorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: { unique: true },
  },
  icon: String,
  color: String,
})

categorySchema.add({ subCategories: [categorySchema] })
```

It's easy to reference the categories themselves. But how can I reference one of the sub categories so that `populate` works correctly?
Thanks

Comment: You need to add an array which takes as well ref to business

Comment: you mean like `category: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories'}]`?

Comment: Yess exactly but since your ref in category is business you put ref :'bussiness'

Comment: So I should reference business from category? The opposite of what I want?

Comment: In shortly you need to do in both ways  :1-the parent which include multiple child's in this case each category has many business u should add array like i said in the top for categories that reference business so each category will know its children 2- the child should contain one  variable which contain the reference to its parent

Comment: There is a lot of reasons why u should do it that way most important is deleting not only delete a business but also remove its id from the array in its parent category another reason let's say u want to render all business of one class its a bad solution to search each business to check if its parent is that category but what is a good solution is going to this category and from its array u have all its children business and you can just find them and render